# Cannot continue the bash script after creating a virtual environment using pipenv

Tags: python-3.x, django, bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm writing a **bash** script that automates the process of **creating a django project** and creating some folders and files that is necessary for a django project.

The problem here is, when I create and activate the virtual environment using the `pipenv shell` command, The virtual environment is created and activated but the next command is not executed. The script just **waits to exit the virtual environment** and when I exit/deactivate the virtual environment, then the next lines of the bash script gets executed.

My next line is `pipenv install django`. When this line is executed, django is installed in the virtual environment and again it waits for the user to exit the virtual environment and when I exit the environment, the next line is executed. But my next line is `django-admin startproject myproject` when this line is executed, I'm getting the error `command not found`. Yes I know why I'm getting this error. The environment is deactivated and it can't recognize the `django-admin` command.

Also, I'm running this script as a **superuser**.
I'm using `wsl2`.

**my code:**

```
mkdir "django_project"
cd "django_project"
pipenv shell
pipenv install django
read -p "Enter your project name: " PROJECT_NAME
django-admin startproject "$PROJECT_NAME"
cd "$PROJECT_NAME"
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

Once I run this script, I get this in the command line,

```
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
root@LENOVO:/home/ubuntu/USER/Bash_Projects/test_folder/django_project#  . /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/django_project-IyKPiglU/bin/activate
(django_project) root@LENOVO:/home/ubuntu/USER/Bash_Projects/test_folder/django_project# exit
exit
Installing django...
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (a6086c)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a6086c)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
Enter your project name: test_project1
create_django_project.sh: line 6: django-admin: command not found
create_django_project.sh: line 7: cd: test_project1: No such file or directory
```

After this I terminated the script with `^C`

The **Pipfile** is created successfully.
The **requirements.txt** file is also created and all the packages are updated in the requirements.txt file.

My **question** is how to continue the script after activating the environment without deactivating it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by using just `pip3` without `pipenv`

#### `pip3 install django`

in Super user mode use this command line

#### `sudo -s`

And it works for me
My machine is UBUNTU 20.04
PYTHON VERSION 3.8.10